# How to pass NSMutable arrays to table view?

Tags: nsmutablearray

I am having three buttons in a view. and three actions for three buttons. In the first view i have declared three buttons and three actions for that three buttons.
In the next view i have taken table view. And I have taken three mutable arrays.
If the first button is pressed the first mutable array items is to be passed into tableview.
If the second button is pressed the second mutable array items is to be passed into tableview.
If the third button is pressed the third mutable array items is to be passed into tableview.
Can anybody give me the code.

Comment: "Can anybody give me the code" is not the sort of thing that you should add to a question on SO. We're here to help you, not spoon feed you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple..you just need to change the `datasource` of the tableView.... in `cellForRowAtindexPath` method whatever array you are passing just change that on `buttonClick` event and reload the `tableView`

**Hope this will help you.**

**Edit Added : for `NSNotification`**

**FirstView.m**

```
-(void)buttonAction{

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"changeArray" object:yourArray userInfo:nil];

}
```

**SecondView.m**

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:) name:@"changeArray" object:nil];

}


-(void)receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification)iNotification{
      NSMutableArray *myArray = [iNotification object];
    //do your changes.

}
```

Comment: I am having action methods in firstview.h/m
and table view is in secondeview.h/m
how to write action in firstview.h about the arrays in secondview.h

Comment: Ok..if you have object of SecondView initialised in FirstView then you can access the tableView from FirstView class...
or else one more method is to use NSNotification...send a NSNotification from FirstView button action and observe it in SecondView...then in selector method you can do the necessary changes.

Comment: in first.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 
    one=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [one addObject:@"abc"];
    [one addObject:@"def"];
    
    two=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [two addObject:@"ghi"];
    [two addObject:@"jkl"];
    
    three=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [three addObject:@"mho"];
    [three addObject:@"par"];
}

-(IBAction)one:(id)sender
{
}
-(IBAction)two:(id)sender
{
}
-(IBAction)three:(id)sender
{
}

can you tell me now what to write in actions and how to pass these arrays into second.m and make visible in tableview

Comment: @Kartheek : check the answer..I have edited it...this is how you can pass the array from FirstView to SecondView